# SelectPDF not maintaining CSS in Razor

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, razor-pages, selectpdf

The PDF generated by selectPDF does not maintain the CSS styles. This code works fine on webforms, but it does not work on Razor pages.

Head:

`<base href="http://localhost:5237/" />`

`<link href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

C#

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var htmlData = @"<p class=""h1 text-center fw-bold"">Test</p>";

    HtmlToPdf converter = new();
    converter.Options.PdfCompressionLevel = PdfCompressionLevel.Best;
    converter.Options.MarginTop = 10;
    converter.Options.MarginLeft = 10;
    converter.Options.MarginRight = 10;

    var baseUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}";

    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlData, baseUrl);
    var pdfBytes = doc.Save();
    doc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline");

    return File(pdfBytes, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: could you try adding the css link like this "<link rel='stylesheet' href='cssFilePath' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: @JalpaPanchal What does cssFilePath mean? Like the file path on the server to the css file? Isn't that what the baseUrl is for?

Comment: could you try adding type='text/css' media='all' in your stylesheet link

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I did it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: could you open network tab and check the css file path what it is showing is that pointing to the correct location or not. also try using the absolute ath for a test purpose